# What is the difference between a mixin classes and standard multiple inheritance in python

Tags: python, oop

Python has the ability to make multiple inheritance, I recently learned about a technique to use mixins. My question is, how do mixins differ from standard multiple inheritance in Python? I am used to mixins in Scala and Ruby, where they are quite distinct from multiple inheritance (although still related).

To clarify, I am specifically asking about if there's any mechanical difference, or if this is just style/duck typing.

Comment: In Python, mixins are an application of multiple inheritance.

Comment: Is there any mechanical difference between the two? Or is it all just convention?

Comment: @Snark I will say multiple inheritance is just one of implementation of mixins concept.